# Call to function 'CFUUIDCreate' returns a Core Foundation object with a +1 retain count

Tags: iphone, ios, sharekit

Added share kit group to the project and found so many compile warnings fixed most of them but few are still showing.

This one is from  OAMutableURLRequest.m class

```
- (void)_generateNonce
{
CFUUIDRef theUUID = CFUUIDCreate(NULL);
CFStringRef string = CFUUIDCreateString(NULL, theUUID);
NSMakeCollectable(theUUID);// **Reference count decremented on this line**
nonce = (NSString *)string; //**Incorrect decrement of the reference count of an object that is not owned at this point by the caller on this line**
}
```

Have no idea how to fix this one.

Thanks for help.

Answer (score 0):

Solved it. Actually i was not share that what to release in this case but when i added

```
 - (void)_generateNonce
 {
CFUUIDRef theUUID = CFUUIDCreate(NULL);
CFStringRef string = CFUUIDCreateString(NULL, theUUID);
NSMakeCollectable(theUUID);
nonce = (NSString *)string;
//[string autorelease];
CFRelease (theUUID);
}
```

It worked. Looks like i was responsible to release the theUUID which i allocated in CFUUIDCreate.